# ArcPy SearchCursor : AddMessage with field value

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I'm trying to get a message in ArcMap dialox box showing the features IDs that have null value in attributes X, Y, or Z.

*myFeatureClass*

| ID_FIELD | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 140160 | 350350 | 450 |
| 102 | 140165 | 350348 |  |
| 103 |  | 350300 | 160 |

I'm looking to have a message with IDs **102** and **103**.

The code I have:

```py
fc = "myFeatureClass"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["X", "Y", "Z"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None:
           arcpy.AddError("Feature n°{0} is missing a value for coordinates".format(row.getValue("ID_FIELD")))
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Did you get any error with the code or anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is only checking if the value the first field in the list is None. You need to alter your code to check X, Y, and Z and return the ID_FIELD in the error message.

```
fc = "myFeatureClass"   
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["ID_FIELD", "X", "Y", "Z"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if None in row[1:]:
            arcpy.AddError("Feature n°{0} is missing a value for coordinates".format(row[0]))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you!